# Consul Intentions are not working for consul services

Tags: consul

My consul set up is as follows: -

```
consul-01 server on 192.168.30.112
consul-02 server on 192.168.30.113
consul-03 server on 192.168.30.114
consul-client on 192.168.30.115
consul-client on 192.168..30.116
```

I have registered 3 .NET Core services viz. service1, service2 and service3. 2 instances of service1 and service2 running on 192.168.30.115 and 192.168.30.116. 1 instance of service3 is running on 192.168.30.116. My use case is that service1 is talking to service2 and service2 in turns talking with service3. All is working fine. Now when i defined an intention as `consul intention create -deny service1 service2`, I am supposed that it must give me an error when I hit the url of service1, but it gives proper output to me. I am not using any sidecar-proxy in my setup. I just want to know that whether intentions only work with side-car proxy or they work work without it also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consul intentions are authorization polices that allow you to control access between applications within a service mesh. You must use a sidecar proxy, or [natively integrate your application](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/native/go) with the mesh, in order to use intentions. They are not applicable if you are only using Consul for service discovery.

Comment: Thanks Blake. Got the point. But as per https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/proxies/built-in it is stated that built in proxy is not supported for production setup. So I believe I have to learn Envoy proxy for this. Any other options apart from Envoy?

Comment: That's right, the built-in proxy is not really for production use. Consul does not test it as widely as Envoy, and it only supports L4 routing of traffic. Consul's L7 routing features require Envoy. That said, you shouldn't really have to learn Envoy to get started. Consul does most of the heavy lifting for you. Is there a particular operational concern you have with using Envoy?

Comment: No, not any concern to use Envoy. Only that i have to look to one more new thing. That's it. Well not an issue I will look at it. Thanks.