# Restricting communication from a service which is consul connect enabled to non consul connect service through intention?

Tags: kubernetes, service, consul

If we have two service for example

- Front-end (*which is consul-connect enabled*)
- Back-end (*which is not consul-connect enabled*).

Is it possible to restrict communication between then through intention. Provided we use Consul-Sync from to moved ***k8s*** service into consul catalog. Then back-end which is not consul-connect enabled will show in intention. I tried setting deny between **Front-end -> Back-end**. If not working Front-end is hitting Back-end. I am missing something Or its like Authorization can only happen between two consul-connect enabled service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was recently answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68432317/12384224.

Consul intentions are authorization polices that allow you to control access between applications within a service mesh. You must use a sidecar proxy, or [natively integrate your application](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/native/go) with the mesh, in order to use intentions. They are not applicable if you are only using Consul for service discovery, or your application is not part of the service mesh.

Comment: I have one more question. Then what's the purpose of enabling consul sync process ? It imports all the k8 service into consul. Those are available in the drop down on intentions which we cannot use as there are not part of service mesh. I am able to hit all the k8 services without even enabling sync process. What's the use case of sync process then ?

Comment: Consul Service Sync is designed to be use when you are only using Consul for service discovery. It allows you to take services from multiple Kubernetes clusters, and register them into Consul (and subsequently Consul -> K8s) so that they are discoverable across all of your clusters. When you are using service mesh, you should disable service sync so that Consul only registers the sidecars in the catalog, not the Kubernetes Service objects, since connections through the mesh will route to the destination port exposed by the sidecar, and not the actual Service port.